# What is the cause of this "std::runtime_error"?

Tags: error-log

What is the cause of the ["std::runtime_error"](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=652305.msg16957675#msg16957675) error below?

> a@a-Peppy:~/monero$ ./monero-blockchain-export --output-file /media/a/SanDisk64GB/
>
> 2016-Nov-22 20:07:27.628966 Starting...
>
> 2016-Nov-22 20:07:27.629007 Setting log level = 0
>
> 2016-Nov-22 20:07:27.629024 Export output file: /media/a/SanDisk64GB/
>
> 2016-Nov-22 20:07:27.629041 Initializing source blockchain (BlockchainDB)
>
> 2016-Nov-22 20:07:27.629501 database: lmdb
>
> 2016-Nov-22 20:07:27.629525 Loading blockchain from folder /home/a/.bitmonero/lmdb ...
>
> 2016-Nov-22 20:07:27.690936 Blockchain initialized. last block: 1185530, d0.h0.m13.s53 time ago, current difficulty: 3744774366
>
> 2016-Nov-22 20:07:27.690974 Source blockchain storage initialized OK
>
> 2016-Nov-22 20:07:27.690986 Exporting blockchain raw data...
>
> 2016-Nov-22 20:07:27.691000 Storing blocks raw data...
>
> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
>
> what():  Error reading expected number of bytes
>
> Aborted
>
> a@a-Peppy:~/monero$

Comment: This is actually super interesting, despite it appearing to be a random error.  If you would alter your question title and tags, I imagine it will be very helpful for future users who encounter this same issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [developer hyc](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=652305.msg16961063#msg16961063) the error is cause my not specifying a file name and can be resolves in the following manner:

> "Use an actual filename for --output-file, not a directory name."